# BroadcastReCeiver internal implementation

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to understand how broadcast receiver works internally.

What happens internally when I call `registerReceiver()` method? Does it create a service internally ?

What happens internally when I call `sendBroadcast`?

If I have to implement my own `BroadcastReceiver` class (without extending the Android `BroadcastReceiver` class) how can I achieve it?

I did a lot of research, but I only found how `BroadcastReceiver` works. I looked at the Android source code too to find out how it works, but it didn't help either.

Comment: "What happens internally..." -- IMHO, that is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. I suggest that buy a book on Android internals, such as [Karim Yahgmour's](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do).

Comment: If i have to implement my own BroadcastReceiver is there anyway ican achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you need to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` without extending Android `BroadcastReceiver`. This is not possible. The Android framework handles the dispatching and delivery of all broadcast `Intent`s to all components that have registered themselves as being listeners for those `Intent`s. When some application calls `sendBroadcast()`, Android checks if any `BroadcastReceiver`s have registered as listener for that `Intent` and if it finds any, it instantiates the component (if it isn't already instantiated) and then calls the component's `onReceive()` method.

If you don't extend Android's `BroadcastReceiver` you cannot register your component as a listener and Android will not call your class' `onReceive()`.

NOTE: Please explain what it is you really want to do if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Android... but expert in everything else :P haha just kidding, i think that a BroadcastReceiver it's like a kind of (linux) crontab, it seems like Android already have some kind of piece of software (or internal service) running for this, and when you use it... you "program it" (to that "service") with selected filters and stuff, that's why is being called even if your app isn't running. OR MAYBE i'm TOTALLY WRONG :) but that's how i see it.